App Icon Showing with White Background in Android Studio (Kotlin)
I'm trying to display my app icon without a white background in my Android project using Kotlin. Despite following standard procedures, the icon still appears with a white background. Here’s what I’ve done
enter image description here I want my app icon to look like this

Prepared a transparent PNG icon:

Created the icon in Photoshop, ensuring the background is transparent.

Saved the icon in PNG format.



Added the icon to mipmap folders:

Placed the icon in all mipmap directories (e.g., mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, etc.).


Updated AndroidManifest.xml:

Set the android:icon attribute to the correct icon in AndroidManifest.xml:
xml

<application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"> <!-- Other settings --> </application>



Created Adaptive Icons:

Used the Image Asset tool in Android Studio to create adaptive icons.

Set the Foreground Layer to the transparent icon and the Background Layer to None.



Cleaned and rebuilt the project:

Ran Build > Clean Project and Build > Rebuild Project.


Verified PNG format:

Confirmed the icon is a transparent PNG.


Restarted the emulator/device:

Restarted both the emulator and the device, but the white background persists.

Screenshot:
enter image description here





Try Settings > Display > Theme and set a different theme. Themes will provide a background color on their own. If you change to dark mode and the background is suddenly black, you'll know where the color is coming from and that Android is actually respecting the transparent background of your image.

This behavior is determined by the device’s launcher app. You cannot override it from your app.

It means you cannot adjust or control such behavior.
